# Golang: Compare XML structures

Tags: xml, testing, go

I need to write a test to verify server response. Response must contain certain headers and xml body.
First, How can I check that the required headers are present in the response.
 And how can I compare received XML and required XML.

For example. Response must contain header "Serv". And body must me contain xml with object "person"

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: Keep-Alive
Serv: "any-string"
Content-Length: 0
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<person>
  <name>string-value</name>
</person>
```

How can I check that response contain header "Serv" and contain body xml with element person and name

Answer (score 0):

The headers are accessible through `http.Response.Header` and the body can be read from `http.Request.Body` e.g. via `ioutil.ReadAll`. Then you can compare the expected to the actual data via standard means.

But maybe you should explain more where the actual problem is and what you tried and why it failed.

Comment: Ok, I figured out with headers. However I can't compare XML. I'm reading body via ioutil.ReadAll or xml.Unmarshal. But how do I know that the body contains any certain element?

Comment: If you know it actually **is** wellformed xml than a simple `bytes.Contains("<person>")` could be enough.